# Como estilizar resultados feitos com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Decidi fazer um programa fácil que envolvesse html, css e javascript. Esse programa multiplica e divide 2 números aleatórios. 
O que estou em dúvida é como mostrar o resultado com o mesmo CSS. Por exemplo, ficar com o fundo azul e os resultados aparecerem no lugar dos inputs (que estão centralizados)

```
<h1>Multiplicando e Dividindo</h1>

    <form id="formulario-calculo">
        <fieldset id="qual-valor1"> 
                <label for="valor1">Digite o primeiro número</label>
                <input id="valor1" name="valor1" type="text" required>
        </fieldset> 
        <fieldset id="qual-valor2">   
                <label for="valor2">Digite o segundo número</label>
                <input id="valor2" name="valor2" type="text"required>
        </fieldset> 
        <button type="submit" id="botao-calcular"><strong>Calcular</strong></button>
    </form>

    <script>
    var botaoCalcular = document.querySelector("#botao-calcular");
    botaoCalcular.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = document.querySelector("#formulario-calculo");

        var valor1 = form.valor1.value; 
        var valor2 = form.valor2.value;

        var multiplicacao = (valor1 * valor2);
        var divisao = (valor1 / valor2);

        document.write("Multiplicando os dois valores teremos: " + multiplicacao + "<br>");
        document.write("Dividindo os dois valores teremos: " + divisao);
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
vertical-align:baseline;
list-style:none;
}

fieldset {
    border:none;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: #69F;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 30px; 
}

#valor1, #valor2 {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 46.5%;
    margin-right: 46.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}   

#botao-calcular {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: darkblue;
}
```

Comment: É mais fácil ajudar quando você já coloca um link para um jsfiddle.com ou codepen.io com seu código :)

Answer (score 1):

Quando você retorna sua resposta, você usa `document.write`para escrever o resultado. `document` significa o documento inteiro.

O que podemos fazer é adicionar uma div para exibir o resultado.

No HTML, adicionamos uma div `<div id="resultado"></div>` logo abaixo do `</fieldset>`.

No JS, trocamos o `document.write` pela div que acabamos de criar, com `document.getElementById('resultado')`. Precisamos também mudar o `write` para `innerHTML`, já que estamos dentro de uma div. Isso muda um pouco como escrever o código:

```
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 
"Multiplicando os dois valores teremos: " + multiplicacao + "<br> 
Dividindo os dois valores teremos: " + divisao;
```

Coloquei tudo junto porque não precisava dividir :)

Veja o exemplo em https://codepen.io/mapreuss/pen/vPXYGx

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece aí é que você sobrescreve toda página Html com **document.write**, por isso ela perde a formatação CSS, existem muitas formas de fazer o que quer, uma delas é esconder o form e mostrar o resultado no seu lugar:

```js
var botaoCalcular = document.querySelector("#botao-calcular");
var formulario = document.getElementById("#formulario-calculo");
var mostraResult = document.getElementById("resultado");

botaoCalcular.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form = document.querySelector("#formulario-calculo");

  var valor1 = form.valor1.value;
  var valor2 = form.valor2.value;

  var multiplicacao = (valor1 * valor2);
  var divisao = (valor1 / valor2);
  
  form.style.display = "none";
  resultado.style.display = "inline-block";

  resultado.innerHTML = `
    Multiplicando os dois valores teremos: ${multiplicacao} <br><br>
    Dividindo os dois valores teremos: ${divisao}
  `;
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  list-style: none;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: #69F;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
}

#valor1,
#valor2 {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 46.5%;
  margin-right: 46.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

#botao-calcular {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: darkblue;
}

#resultado {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Multiplicando e Dividindo</h1>

<form id="formulario-calculo">
  <fieldset id="qual-valor1">
    <label for="valor1">Digite o primeiro número</label>
    <input id="valor1" name="valor1" type="text" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="qual-valor2">
    <label for="valor2">Digite o segundo número</label>
    <input id="valor2" name="valor2" type="text" required>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" id="botao-calcular"><strong>Calcular</strong></button>
</form>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona a linha de estilo após escrever o documento.

```
document.write("Multiplicando os dois valores teremos: " + multiplicacao + "<br>Dividindo os dois valores teremos: " + divisao);
document.body.style.background = "darkblue"
```

espero que ajude

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp